# The percentage of xxx vs. The proportion of xxx?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Which expression would be better in formal academic writing?

1. The percentage of incidence is approaching approximately 80%.
2. The proportion of incidence is approaching approximately 80%.

I believe both ways would be fine, but would like to know any subtle difference in nuance.

Comment: Neither sound idiomatic to me. We don't have the *full* context, but my guess is you don't want either *percentage* or *proportion*, OR the word *approximately*. And quite possibly *incidence* isn't a good word for the context. How about *X now happens in nearly 80% of [cases under consideration]?*

Comment: "approaching approximately" sounds like you're deliberately trying to be vague or misleading! Like something from *How To Lie With Statistics*.

Comment: [Percentage/ratio/proportion confusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4331538/21813)

Answer (score 0):

There is a small difference, in that when describing percentage, you must give a value out of one hundred. As for proportion, you can say 8 out of 10 times.... or 4 out of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are awkward and redundant.

Say:  "**The incidence is approximately 80%.**"

or:  "**The incidence approaches 80%**".

Comment: "The incidence (today) is approximately 80%." "The incidence is (in the course of) approaching 80%."

Comment: @ryang The first example here makes sense, the second does not.    If you were trying to make a point by way of example and not asking if these are grammatical, please reword the second sentence so that it does not use "in the course of".

Comment: Please explain your downvote so that the answer can be improved.

Comment: I commented here rather than immediately under the OP to complement your suggestions, my second suggestion is in the context of approaching an asymptote, and no I didn't downvote your answer.